# How to hide cursor in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I wonder how to hide cursor in QML, QT 5.7.

I tried to use

```
QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::BlankCursor));
```

and

```
app.setOverrideCursor( QCursor( Qt::BlankCursor ) );
```

But both doesn't work.

```
/home/QTProjects/main.cpp:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class QCursor'
     QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::BlankCursor));
                                                               ^
```

And if it possible can I hide cursor within QML not on C++ side.

Comment: `#include <QCursor>` so you can use your first code in your `main.cpp`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a disabled overlay `MouseArea` to hide it:

```
  Button {
    onClicked: console.log("clicked")
  }

  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    enabled: false
    cursorShape: Qt.BlankCursor
  }
```

Just put the mouse area in the bottom of your `main.qml`, it will be transparent to events but still override the cursor shape.

Comment: only works when I move the mouse, I still see it when the application start in the upper-left corner (Raspberry Pi)

Answer (score 4):

you should include QCursor into main.cpp and call

```
QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::BlankCursor));
```